# Compare response 200 and I require 'true' as answer

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, compare

```
print(response)
if(response=="<Response [200]>"):
   print("true")
else:
   print("false")
```

1. getting response as '`<Response [200]>`'
2. getting false
3. require True as output

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that your response is exactly the same as your comparison? As written, your problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @DavidBuck , yes i am getting 200 response. But writing if(response=="<Response [200]>"), gives me false. i want to know the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The builtin function `print` will automatically apply `str()` to any object that is not already `str`.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#print) So what gets printed is actually `str(response)`, which is a string representation of `response`, kinda like a summary. Comparing the human-readable `str` summary of any object to the object itself will only return true if that object was already a `str`. That is not the case here, as you're dealing with `requests.Response` object.

For your purposes, use `.status_code` to check:

**Example:**

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733985/compare-response-200-and-i-require-true-as-answer')

print(response)
if(response.status_code==200):
   print("true")
else:
   print("false")
```

**Output:**

```
<Response [200]>
true
```